# sudo apt-get install -d zsh. Can not find where it downloaded the file

Tags: linux, apt

After running command

```
sudo apt-get install -d zsh
```

I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  zsh-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  zsh
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 278 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,716 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Download complete and in download only mode
```

I can not find where actually did it download the file of zsh package.
There is no such file in the directory where I am located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download an individual package file into the current directory you can use `apt-get download packagename`.

What `apt-get install -d packagename` does is to do the first step of *install*. Ie, it downloads the package and all of its not yet installed dependencies into the local cache. The package cache can be found in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.